# Copy \ Move Image resizing to the original image size VBS \ BAT?

Tags: image, batch-file, vbscript, copy

Using this code the .jpg image size will match the default screen resolution (in this case: 1280x1024)

```
dim filesys, oShell
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

sup = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings ("%APPDATA%")
des = "../../chrome/OPCEN/images/WALLPERSONA/"
destfile= "../../chrome/OPCEN/images/WALLPERSONA/TranscodedWallpaper.jpg"
sourcefile= sup & "\Microsoft\Windows\themes\TranscodedWallpaper.jpg"

If filesys.FileExists(sourcefile) Then
   filesys.CopyFile sourcefile, destfile
End If
```

to complete my goal I also need to replace the .jpg with a custom any size image but keeping the same size of the original (I can't use fixed values because the screen resolution can vary) my try is starting with this

```
@ECHO OFF
move "%APPDATA%\Styled+\Styled+BoX\*.jpg" "..\..\chrome\OPCEN\images\WALLPERSONA\TranscodedWallpaper.jpg" 
exit
```

Comment: What do you need a batch file for? you can move a file using the VBScript too! Also ,would it not make more sense to determine the screen size in pixels and then choose an image which matches that?

Comment: The bat file is for a second independent option and it can also be a VBScript as you said, that's why I'm asking for a "VBS \ BAT ?"

Comment: <choose an image which matches that? > well I can't ask the user to self  resize the chosen image but I'm ready to try new solutions